# Unexpected long execution time for zeroinfl()

Tags: r, performance

I am running a zero inflated regression model function for a 498,501 rows dataframe on a 32gb linux machine with a 2.6GHz CPU. I used the following command

```
library(pscl)
zeroinfl(response ~ predictor1 + predictor2, data=dataframe, dist = "negbin", EM = TRUE)
```

R has now been computing for more that 48 hours now with no warning or error message.

I am a bit puzzled since a traditional `lm()` on the same data delivers almost instantaneously. Should I suspect some problem with my command? Or is it just a very slow function?

Comment: First, see how much memory is being used. If it's started to swap it may take a very long time to finish. Second, try running on a small subset of the data and gradually increasing it to get an idea of execution time. I suspect the EM algorithm could be rather slow.